# trying to add extension and login using selenium but captcha found after one time login I don't know why

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to add a helium 10 extension using selenium python but when I'm going to login captcha is showing. I don't know what to do now...
Can I use an incognito window for that?
I don't know what I'm doing wrong.. can anyone help me?
below is the code

```
chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
chrome_options.add_argument('start-maximized')
chrome_options.add_extension('helenium.crx')
chrome_options.add_argument('--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection')
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation']);
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[contains(text(),"Log In")]').click()
driver.find_element_by_name('LoginForm[email]').send_keys('my_email')
driver.find_element_by_name('LoginForm[password]').send_keys('my_password')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[text()="Log In"]').click()
```

@supputuri

Comment: you cant get around the captcha with a script.

Comment: Is there any way to we can do that browser neber knw that we're using selenium like undetectable?